# WooCommerce update after clicking "buy" button

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

WooCommerce is a fantastic plugin, but i need this feature:
I need the stock is updated just a customer clicks on the buy button, and not after checkout. In this way a single product in stock can not be ordered at the same time by two people. Can anyone help me? I hope I was clear, I used Google trad;-)

Comment: Have you checked Woocommerce support? http://www.woothemes.com/support/

Comment: Yes, but it seems that the problem is not discussed. The stock is updated after checkout, but i want to prevent that two people do the same order of a single product. So I need to update the stock immediately after the click on "add to cart"

Comment: Have you considered posting into their forum or asking from their helpdesk?

Comment: I'm thinking, but it is a fee, and it costs a lot. I posted a question in the community forum

Comment: No, but I want to be sure I did not make any mistakes in the configuration. If it is a customization, I am happy to receive support from the development team

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce -> catalog -> add to cart -> Redirect to the cart page after successful addition

That´s what you´re looking for?